# Disable conversion of & to shortcut indicator (winforms)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, escaping

I have a tab control (in my case a UltraTabControl from Infragistics) and I add a new tab.

The text of this new tab is set to "Escape &Characters".

```
lTab.Text = "Escape &Characters"
```

When visualizing the tab control the **&** will become an _ (underscore) for the next character - in this case "C"
[image]

I know that **&** is the Microsoft way of indicating a shortcut character - but is there any way of disabling this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure beacuse i can't test it now, but have you tried lTab.Text = @"Escape &Characters" ??

Comment: I'm working in vb.net so I can't use that @. I've tried System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape but that does not help. The string is not changed, I can look at it and it is "Escape &Characters" - correct - but just displayed "resolved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261320).

If you want & in your menu/title name you have to pass it as &&, so right now I do:

```
inputText.Replace("&","&&")
```

Comment: then maybe this is shorter lTab.Text = inputText.Replace("&","&&")

Comment: You are right - shorter is better (in this case). I modified the post to reflect your suggestion. Thanks